# Javascript 'Crossfade' Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, fade

I have an array of values - each value represents the intensity of a lighting Channel (0-255) that will be controlled. 
Each array holds a 'scene'.

I want to cross fade between 'scenes' but can't work out an elegant way to do it.

In Javascript, how can I fade the array of oldValues to array of newValues over the given duration with a given update interval (eg. 25ms)?

I've found something very similar to what I'm after linked below, but can't work out how to apply this to work on an array of values.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshuapinter/8uasm7ko/

```
//EXAMPLE
var oldValues = [0,124,12,200];      // Initial Values
var newValues = [255,255,255,255];   // Target Values

var duration = 4000;                 // Time for transition in Milliseconds
var interval = 25;                   // 40 intervals (frames) per second.

CODE GOES HERE
```

Comment: 1. calculate the step size (delta value per interval);
2. set a temporary variable to the initial value;
3. use "setInterval" to schedule interval event, in the callback: a) when not reach the final value, calculate the current stage value, take action & assign it to temporary variable, b); b) when reach the final value, "clearInterval".

Comment: `var timeelapsed = ...; var ratio = Math.min(1,timeelapsed/duration); var midValues = oldValues.map(function(o,i) {var n=newValues[i]; return o+(n-o)*ratio;});`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that calculates the number of steps to execute, calculates the stepping value, and calls itself over and over with a `setTimeout` until there are no steps left:

```
function animateLight(light, start, end, duration, interval) {
  // Calculate number of steps
  var nbSteps = Math.ceil(duration / interval);
  if(nbSteps == 0){ return; }
  // Calculate value to add/substract to the current value
  var step = (end - start) / nbSteps;
  var current = start + step;
  light.querySelector('.light').style.opacity = current / 255;
  light.querySelector('.value').innerText = parseInt(current, 10);

  setTimeout(function(){
    animateLight(light, current, end, duration - interval, interval)
  }, interval);
}
```

### Demo

```js
var lights = document.getElementsByClassName('light-wrapper'); // Light DOM elements
var oldValues = [0,124,12,200];      // Initial Values
var newValues = [255,255,255,255];   // Target Values

var duration = 4000;                 // Time for transition in Milliseconds
var interval = 25;                   // 40 intervals (frames) per second.

for(var i=0; i<lights.length; i++) {
    animateLight(lights[i], oldValues[i], newValues[i], duration, interval);
}

function animateLight(light, start, end, duration, interval) {
  // Calculate number of steps
  var nbSteps = Math.ceil(duration / interval);
  if(nbSteps == 0){ return; }
  // Calculate value to add/substract to the current value
  var step = (end - start) / nbSteps;
  var current = start + step;
  light.querySelector('.light').style.opacity = current / 255;
  light.querySelector('.value').innerText = parseInt(current, 10);

  setTimeout(function(){
    animateLight(light, current, end, duration - interval, interval)
  }, interval);
}
```

```css
body{
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.light-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

.light{
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 3em auto .8em auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .4em #fff, 0 0 .8em #fff, 0 0 .8em #fff, 0 0 1.2em #fff,  0 0 3em #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-wrapper">
  <div class="light"></div> <div class="value">255</div>
</div>
<div class="light-wrapper">
  <div class="light"></div> <div class="value">255</div>
</div>
<div class="light-wrapper">
  <div class="light"></div> <div class="value">255</div>
</div>
<div class="light-wrapper">
  <div class="light"></div> <div class="value">255</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the value by using the slope of the values.

```js
function getValue(start, end, parts, part) {
    return start + (end - start) * part / parts;
}

var oldValues = [0,124,12,200];      // Initial Values
var newValues = [255,255,255,255];   // Target Values

var duration = 4000;                 // Time for transition in Milliseconds
var interval = 25;                   // 40 intervals (frames) per second.

var i = 0,
    parts = duration / interval;

for (i = 0; i <= parts; i++)  {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += oldValues.map(function (a, j) {
        return Math.floor(getValue(a, newValues[j], parts, i));
    }).join() + '\n';
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```